# jQuery how to disable / enable Submit button in dialog

Tags: jquery, button

I have a dialog:

```js
$("#ceresume").dialog({
  modal: true,
  draggable: true,
  resizable: false,
  position: {
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: window
  },
  show: "blind",
  hide: "blind",
  height: DIALOG_HEIGHT,
  width: DIALOG_WIDTH,
  dialogClass: "ui-dialog-osx",
  buttons: {
    "Submit": function() {
      /// ...
    }
  }
});
```

I want to disable the Submit button so I tried this:

```
$("#ceresume, button:contains('Submit'])").prop("disabled", true);
```

Whilst:

```
$("#ceresume, button:contains('Submit'])")
```

Appears to return the correct results, setting the disabled attribute to true is not disabling the button.  How do I do this?

Comment: $(":submit").attr("disabled", false); but actually I think you might be missing the correct selector maybe? I had to think harder before posting my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ] character inside the "contains" must be removed, it's causing an error.

So your command should be:

```
$("#ceresume,button:contains('Submit')").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice the square bracket typo.

Comment: A comma is required after the ID and before the button tag or the query does not work.

Comment: You are right. I thought that dialog would put the button inside the #ceresume dialog, but it doesn't. It puts it in a different container. That means that $("#ceresume button ... ") won't work. $("#ceresume, button ...") will, as well as just $("button..."), since the button has nothing to do with the "#ceresume" container actually. However, any of those it is disabling every button on the page which contains Submit. That may not be what you want. Anyhow, thanks for your comment, I'll fix that part of the answer!